# How to call spring form:checkboxes component in javascript?

Tags: javascript, spring

I am using spring form tags, want to call  component in a javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem,

```
var formElements = document.getElementById('form_id');
     for (var i = 0; i , formElements .length; i++)
       {
        if (formElements [i].type == 'checkbox')
          {
           formElements [i].disabled=true;             
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rendered as regular hTML form so using Jquery you can access it as regular HTML form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("#compponentId").val());
      });
</script>
```